# Android - getter/setter not passing one specific String

Tags: java, android, android-studio-3.0

In MainActivity.java, I have the following

```
classofmethods new1 = new classofmethods();
static getset GS = new GS();
.....
code .....
settle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
String keyword1 = nc.methodName(String, String, int);
GS.setkeyword(keyword1);
try {
//Method 1 makes an API call...Trying to set an //endpoint but the URL prints out as ....keyword=null;
new1.method1();
new1.method2();
new1.method3();
new1.method4();
} catch (Exception e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}
 }
  });
```

GS

```
String keyword = null;
public String getkeyword() {
        return keyword;
    }
    public void setkeyword(String keyword) {
        this.keyword = keyword;
    }
```

My problem is that the onClick executes my desired code, however it will not set the keyword. 
In the GS class, I declared keyword as "public String keyword = null;"
The API when executed in method1() returns null.

I guess it is a timing issue? I have looked at other threads but no solutions. I have another activity that adjust users settings and those values are passed through the API correctly.

Edit: this is why stack overflow has post quality guidelines. I failed to provide enough info.

In my classofmethods:

```
keyword was declared like: public String keyword = GS.getkeyword();
endpoint was specified like: &keyword=" +  keyword

fix was: &keyword=" + MainActivity.GS.getkeyword()
```

Comment: show your model class where you are setting your values

Comment: The value you are setting in the `setkeyword` method is `null`. Put `log` and verify it yourself.

Comment: when I log it in the MainActivity.java, it prints out an actual word. The classofmethods class isn't getting it for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
private String keywword;
public String getkeyword() {
    return keyword;
}
public void setkeyword(String keyword) {
    this.keyword = keyword;
}
```

Comment: Im an idiot that doesn't understand JAVA. See edit for my error + correction